# Upload and run Selenium Java Test

Tags: java, selenium

I have recently started working with Selenium using Java and have written a few tests. I would like to put these tests on some kind of remote host and set them up to run on a schedule.

Is there a free server that I can use to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of hosting, I don't know that you're going to find a 'free' host for an indefinite time period. AWS and Azure both offer free trials of their virtual machine hosts for 12 months (for a single Linux server running continuously):

https://aws.amazon.com/free/
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/

**Make sure that you read the terms and conditions carefully**, because if you run outside of the free guidelines, you will end up getting charged for usage that didn't fall under the rules of their respective free usage periods (e.g. shut everything down before 12 months, don't run 2 servers, etc...).

To run the tests, you should be able to compile your tests into .jar files, and then set them up to run automatically using a cron job (assuming a Linux host):

[Java – Cron job to run a jar file](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-cron-job-to-run-a-jar-file/)